# Pass Image from Listview to another activity

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a Custom listview having a image. Now I need to fetch that image from one activity to another activity.I had used the following code.It works but its fetching the same image size from Listview to another activity but I need to fix its size according to another activity.

```
    ImageView imageview = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.yourImageview);
       Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageview.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
       Intent intent = new Intent(activity.this, Nextactivity.class);
       intent.putExtra("contentTwo", bitmap);

     Bitmap receivedimage =(Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("contentTwo");
    imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yourimageview);
    imageview.setImageBitmap(receivedimage);
```

The adapter code:

```
public Screen(Activity a,
        ArrayList<Data> DataList) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    activity = a;
    bleepDraftDataList = draftDataList;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return bleepDraftDataList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    private ImageView imageViewleft;
    private ImageView imageViewlright;

}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Data = DataList.get(position);
    view = convertView;
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.something, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageViewleft = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.imageViewBleeplinecellleft);
        holder.imageViewlright = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.imageViewBleeplinecellright);



        view.setTag(holder);

    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    if (!Data.creator.image.equals("")) {
        holder.imageViewleft.setTag(""
                + Data.creator.image);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage("" + Data.creator.image,
                activity, holder.imageViewleft);
    }
    if (!Data.preview.equals("")) {
        holder.imageViewright.setTag(""
                + Data.preview);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage("" + Data.preview, activity,
    return view
}
```

}

Comment: I think more easy and less space point of view you have to use one static bitmap object so it assigned on list item click and use on another activity by their static reference ... Wat You Think?

Comment: the problem, is you are taking bitmap from imageview in listview, so it returns size of that imageview only.. Rather than this, try with orginal bitmap which you set for imageView.. Please paste your adapter code, so it will be helpful...

Comment: @Anilkumar I had paste my adapter code..

Comment: Now try this... instead of getting bitmap, get drawable & send that using intents.. like this Drawable drawable=imageview.getDrawable();

Comment: Drawable drawable=imageview.getDrawable();

Answer (score 1):

use this and set how big you want the image to be

```
receivedimage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(receivedimage , 260, 260, false); 

  // 260*260 Width* height change this to your requirement
```

The other thing you can do is , In **PutExtras** get the image path

```
Bitmap receivedimage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);

     imageview.setImageBitmap(receivedimage);
```

Comment: @PratibhaSharma use second method using the image path